# How to use Bitxor for Double Numbers?

Tags: matlab, integer, double, type-conversion, double-precision

I want to use xor for my double numbers in matlab,but bitxor is only working for int numbers. Is there a function that could convert double to int in Matlab?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to apply bitxor to a double ? Only there might be an easier way to achieve your goal.

Comment: In my program I need to use double number between 0,1 .for using bit xor what should I do?

Comment: @saba2085 but are you saying you want to find the xor of like 0.2343 and 0.789787 for example? Because in that case how are you defining xor? Casting to a integer will round off...

Comment: @saba: yes, but *why* do you need to XOR these numbers - this is not normally something you would ever want to do, so it would help to know what the reason behind the question is - that way you might get a better (or more appropriate) answer.

Comment: I think you are trying to run before you walk with this problem. You don't seem to understand the basics of the data types or operations you are talking about. You should read about integers and floating point numeric representations, and then read about bitwise operations such as xor, and how they are usually applied. You do not seem to be listening to anyone's advise on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The functions You are looking for might be: `int8(number)`, `int16(number)`, `uint32(number)` Any of them will convert Double to an Integer, but You must pick the best one for the result You want to achieve. Remember that You cannot cast from Double to Integer without rounding the number.

If I understood You correcly, You could create a function that would simply remove the "comma" from the Double number by multiplying your starting value by 2^n and then casting it to Integer using any of the functions mentioned earlier, performing whatever you want and then returning comma to its original position by dividing the number by 2^n

Multiplying the starting value by 2^n is a hack that will decrease the rounding error.
The perfect value for *n* would be the number of digits after the comma if this number is relatively small.

Please also specify, why are You trying to do this? This doesn't seem to be the optimal solution.

Comment: I think it might make more sense to multiply by `2^n`?

Comment: I  have fuzzy cellular automata with double numbers . At each stage of the implementation  I want use cellular automata rules and after that use bitxor for result and some random number .after that result of using bit xor save to cellular automata for next stage.

Comment: @pivovarit also I think `int16` is more appropriate as `int8` has a max of 127. Otherwise I think this is the correct answer.

Comment: @saba2085 add all of this information to the question, It will make everyone's life easier

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast to an integer:

```
a = 1.003

int8(a)

ans =

1
```

That gives you an 8 bit signed integer, you can also get other size i.e. `int16` or else unsigned i.e. `uint8` depending on what you want to do

Comment: Not like this.I want to save my number completely.my numbers is like these 0.5,0.789 ... and I want to keep this form.

Comment: So then what is `xor` for doubles? How are you defining it?

Comment: look in my program I change  my number[0,256] to number between [0,1]  and I want to use bitxor for my number and  some random number (between [0,1]. when i say change double to int my goal is like this 0.789--->789

Comment: How exactly can I "look in your program" since you haven't provided any code? Why don't you just do it before you scale your numbers? Or else you could multiply them by 256, cast to int16, bitxor, and then divide by 256?

Comment: I have fuzzy cellular automata with double numbers . At each stage of the implementation I want use cellular automata rules and after that use bitxor for result and some random number .after that result of using bit xor save to cellular automata for next stage.

Comment: Yes then multiply by 256,  unint18, divide by 256. Basically do what pivovarit says

Comment: Thank's  Dan and  pivovarit.I found answer.using typecast   typecast(bitxor(typecast(0.3243,'uint64'),typecast(0.12325,'uint64')),'double')

Comment: @saba2085 that is definitely wrong! Please use pivovarit's method instead.